Uploading Images to a SharePoint List
I am creating a SharePoint List.  It is being created on a remote server.  I do not know if that is information that is helpful, but it might be.  The issue I am having is in uploading images to the SharePoint List.  It would be nice to have images for each item in the List so that this can be used by the user to visualise the item that is selected.  But when I try to upload the image, it displays this icon of what I assume to be a broken image  alongside the file name.
Any advice or tips?
Do I need to first upload the image to the server?
For clarity, this is what it looks like when I try to upload an image:
https://youtu.be/KaIz9M8YnXY
